Is there a way to use DirectDependents to indicate whether cell is dependent from other sheet
When you have a dependent in Excel (1), so cell is used by formula on other sheet, it shows it with an icon (2). Now I was wondering if that's also possible via code.

I have tried using range.Directdependents/range.Dependents. But it returns an error because it cant find them.
Of course there is a way by analyzing all formulas of a workbook but that will take time.
Since Excel knows it directly (I can't imagine excel scans all workbook formulas:)). Note I just want to now if it is used, not where (would be nice but not relevant at the moment).

This question is similar to: Programmatically select other sheet precedents or dependents in Excel. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hint: Look for the NavigateArrow method. Otherwise, you'll have to parse formulas indeed.

Thanks for the hints (don't have a clue why I did not find the simular issue, did search for it).
Ended up using below code for testing, which does the trick:
    xlRangeTemp = SubtractRanges(xlRangeRealUsed, xlRangeSameSheet)
For Each rngCell In xlRangeTemp
    arrow = 1
    link = 1

    Try
        rngCell.ShowDependents()
        'watch if dependent is on protected sheet  'to be changed
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Try
        xlPrecedentRange = rngCell.NavigateArrow(False, arrow, link)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    If xlPrecedentRange.Worksheet.Name <> rngCell.Worksheet.Name Then
        If xlRangeOtherSheets Is Nothing Then
            xlRangeOtherSheets = rngCell
        Else
            xlRangeOtherSheets = XL.Union(xlRangeOtherSheets, rngCell)
        End If
    End If
Next
WsClearArrowsBasic (xlWorksheet)

